# How to make background of List cells transparent in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, user-interface, colors, swiftui

I have this simple list that displays custom views. I can't figure out how to change the colour of the background of the cells.

```
List(weeksTasks, id: \.self){ week in
    let index = weeksTasks.firstIndex(of: week)
    WeekPlanRowView(hours: weekHours![index ?? 0], title: week, complete: false)
        .padding(.bottom, 15)
}
```

This is what I have so far:
[image]

I would like to change the white to green, any suggestions?

I have tried this:

```
init(weekNum: Int, weeksTasks: [String], weekDescription: String, hoursPerWeek: Int){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96, alpha: 0)
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96, alpha: 0)
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

and  `.listRowBackground(Color.green)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - use ForEach inside List and apply

```
List {
  ForEach(weeksTasks, id: \.self){ week in
    let index = weeksTasks.firstIndex(of: week)
    WeekPlanRowView(hours: weekHours![index ?? 0], title: week, complete: false)
        .padding(.bottom, 15)
  }
  .listRowBackground(Color.green)      // << here !!
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]